# Live reload browser page. Grunt and Vagrant

Tags: php, yii, gruntjs, vagrant, grunt-contrib-watch

sorry for the mistakes I've made, I'm not Englishman.

So..
First, I have Vagrant machine which is my web server with installed **Yii**, Ngnix, PHP etc. The vm is configured as follows:

```
private_network, 192.168.10.10
forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
synced_folder "www", "/srv/www", :nfs => true # !important
```

Second, I have Grunt which is installed on my local machine and do some tasks(watches *.scss files and converts them to css) within web root which is synced with Vagrant through nfs daemon.

I successfully do my tasks and connect to my web root through browser (localhost:8080) and everything works ok. However, I don't understand how can I implement simple reload browser page when Grunt watches my scss files and finishes to convert them into a single css file.

Could anybody give me some thoughts by simple English?

Comment: Take a look at this don't know if it's the same thing but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382708/how-to-get-grunt-watch-to-live-reload-html-changes-under-different-build-tasks?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, but it is different thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add a browser plugin to your browser and then have watch notify it. More info here at the bottom:
http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/

Comment: I've tried this (livereload option with grunt-contrib-watch), but unfortunately it doesn't work( Nonetheless big thank you! good article!

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov a guess on why it might not be working.  Might your firewalls (in on your main machine or out on your vagrant machine) be blocking the communication of the watch notification?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov Yep, that might be the issue. http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86280-if-you-edit-files-directly-on-your-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268136/grunt-watch-livereload-fatal-error-port-35279-is-already-in-use-by-another-proc

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by just restarting browser! This is little instruction:

1. Gruntfile:

   ```
   watch: {
       scss: {
           files: '<%= path.webapp %>/**/*.scss',
           tasks: ['sass'],
           options: {
               livereload: true, //! important
           },
       },
   }
   ```
2. Add [livereload plugin to the chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en). After CLOSE THE BROWSER!
3. Start the task in command line: `grunt watch`
4. Start the browser. And click to the livereload circle button at the top of the window.
5. Voila! It works.

**IMPORTANT**: there is no reason to worry about the port and address of your 'remote' server, livereload magically detect where need to restart the page. Is works for me as **localhost:8080/webapp.com** and **192.168.10.10/webapp.com** identically